# Correct way to reordering items in a list (nhibernate)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, html-lists

What is the correct way to reorder a list when using NHibernate?

This is my list:

```
    private IList<MediaItem> media = new List<MediaItem>();
    public virtual IList<MediaItem> Media { get { return media.ToReadOnlyCollection(); } }
```

And I'm reordering by passing an ordered list of `MediaItem` ids (`Guid`):

```
    public virtual void UpdateMediaOrder(IList<Guid> mediaIds) {

        // TODO remove any unmatched items
        foreach (var mi in Media)
        {
            int index = mediaIds.IndexOf(mi.Id);
            if (index == -1) 
                index = media.Count() -1;
            media[index] = mi;
        }
    }
```

When I reorder the list (in this case a list containing 3 items), NHibernate executes the following:

```
NHibernate: DELETE FROM PortfolioProjectMedia... 
NHibernate: INSERT INTO PortfolioProjectMedia...
NHibernate: INSERT INTO PortfolioProjectMedia... 
NHibernate: INSERT INTO PortfolioProjectMedia...
```

I guess I expected to see `Updates` rather than clearing the list.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the intended behaviour?

#### Update

In case it wasn't already clear, I need to map my list as a NHibernate List (not a Set or a Bag) so that the index of the items is persisted.

Here's the mapping of the `MediaItem` collection on `Project`. `MediaItem` has no reference to projects. The relationship is many-to-many.

```
        HasManyToMany(p => p.Media)
            .Table("PortfolioProjectMedia")
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProjectId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("MediaItemId")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .AsList(i => i.Column("ListIndex").Type<int>());
```

Comment: Can you show the hbm config file of MediaItem and its parent

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using BAG for mapping MediaItem collection. Have you tried to use SET?

**update**

Try something like this:

```
<set cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="Media">
  <key>
    <column name="Media_id" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="MediaItem" />
</set>


using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

public Media()
{
    this.Media = new HashedSet<MediaItem>();
}
public virtual ISet<MediaItem> Media { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try map your collection as SET with Iesi.Collections.

Comment: I've updated my question - I'm mapping as a `List` not a `Bag` or `Set`